# Identifying diode like symbol with two lines going into the "triangle", used in a H-bridge

Tags: schematics, switching, symbol

I have a question about a special circuit symbol:

[image: Unknown component: diode symbol with two lines going into the "triangle"]

The component is a switch of a H-bridge. I checked a few symbol lists like [here](http://www.wikiwand.com/de/Liste_der_Schaltzeichen_(Elektrik/Elektronik)) or [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Schaltzeichen_(Elektrik/Elektronik)) - but I can't find the right component. What is the meaning / component of this symbol?

This is the full schematic:

[image: Full schematic using the unknown component]

Comment: Some obscure thyristor/SCR/GTO?

Comment: Looks like a thyristor diode.

Comment: How about what the circuit looks like?

Comment: @Andyaka the circuit is a simple H-bridge like http://www.lothar-miller.de/s9y/uploads/Bilder/H-Bridge_1.gif with this component instead of the 4 transistors.

Comment: I don't see that component in what you have directed me to. Why not?

Comment: In other words, show us the symbol *in the context in which you found it.*

Comment: With component I meant the component shown in my question - just replace all transistors of the H-bridge by the component of my question - this is the context.

Comment: It still would be nice to see the original diagram, but I would guess, it means opto-isolators instead of transistors so the EMIs from the motor circuits do not contaminate the rest of the circuit.

Comment: I'm sorry ... due to copyright I cant upload the whole diagram.

Comment: Then due to my impatience I can't be bothered!

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg, so just upload the part that includes these symbols. It will still help us understand the context of your question.

Comment: Otherwise, you need to ask for help from someone you're allowed to share the details of your question with, or just look at the BOM that came with your schematic.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses! - I did a little bit paint :-) ... I added the full context.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg opto-isolators/transistors.  That's probably what that is.

Comment: Does the circuit REALLY show that your four mystery components are connected ONLY at the top and bottom?  What are those lines coming out the side?  Are they really "floating"?  Or are they connected to something?  The best you can do here is gather random guesses since we are unable to see the CONTEXT.  There are many symbols used in schematic diagrams that are not necessarily universally understood. But when viewed IN CONTEXT it is easy for most engineers to figure it out.  But as an isolated case, it is practically impossible to say with any certainty.  "Optical" typically uses ~~ lines.

Comment: @RichardCrowley this is REALLY the whole circuit I got - no other wires or something like this. The circuit is in a script dealing with a single-phase inverter

Comment: Then, how can they be the switches of a H bridge? A component that acts as a switch needs a control input somewhere. Where is this control input? I only see the two poles of the switch in this symbol.

Comment: I'm not sure but it can be an old symbol of varicap. But I have no idea about the use of it and the possible use in the circuit given.

Comment: can you show the gatedrive?  I think it is a piss-poor GTO symbol but the gatedrive will confirm

Comment: @JonRB I have absolutely no other information like the one shown in the question ... I slowly belief the schematic is not totally correct and many information to understand the meaning are missing.

Comment: its part of a Hbridge which would imply force commutated devices. A diode-like symbol is used with two "control lines".  Everything would point towards a GTO, but why you would use one in a H-bridge is beyond me... 3phase inverter sure (if you really,. really had to...)

Comment: If that is all you have (what was the part left out because of "copyright"?), then there is no practical way to identify what are those mystery components.  Assuming the black rectangle is a ferrite bead inductor?  What is the circle (load?) in the middle?  Sorry, this appears to be an impossible question based on what you have revealed.  Too many unknowns.  I can only guess this is a "block diagram" (vs. a real schematic) and those mystery symbols represent SCR or some kind of unidentified thyristor.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a non-standard block-diagram symbol for a uni-polar thyristor such as an SCR, etc.  Absence of context makes any better answer impossible.